# R with dplyr group by and count and sum

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have this df

```
country            Profit
Algeria            10614            
Australia          36036            
Hungary            2964         
Sweden             -26055           
Australia          3777         
Australia          15342
Hungary            12141
Sweden             15373
Algeria            98731
```

I want to count the country and sum profit each country

Like this

```
country     count   sumprofit
Australia   3       ....
Algeria     1       ....
Hungary     2       ....
Sweden      2       ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
            sumprofit = sum(Profit, na.rm = TRUE))

#  country   count sumprofit
#  <chr>     <int>     <int>
#1 Algeria       2    109345
#2 Australia     3     55155
#3 Hungary       2     15105
#4 Sweden        2    -10682
```